# Changing foreign key to another model

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a model:

```
class myModels(model.Model):
    handler =  models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
```

The foreign key hasn't been used so it's always null. Now I want to use it as a foreign key to another model, like this:

```
handler =  models.ForeignKey(Something, blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm using MySQL.The handler has constraints to User model.

Suggestions on how to solve this would be welcome. My first thought would be to drop the column and add it again with the new constraint, but I'm not sure whether dropping a column gets rid of the constraint.

Comment: Please go for South or another migration manager like @jpic mentions, it will _really_ save you time! I personally don't do projects without  South these days, it's that good.

Comment: i found this post to be extremely useful. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470356/mysql-show-create-constraint

i´ll probably end up removing the column and foreign key manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `./manage.py reset yourapp` which will drop the tables of your app, then you'd `syncdb` again. That's what I do during development because it's quick and easy.

There are many other ways: you can install `django-extensions`, run command `./manage.py sqldiff yourapp`, and then run the generated SQL, which will modify the structure according to your models.py.

If you want to know more about schema migrations, [here](http://blog.yourlabs.org/django-schema-migrations-nashvegas-vs-south-v) is an article which gives an overview of the current options.